# Is it possible to use ClearInterval inside static getDerivedStateFromPRops method in React?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I have set an Interval and did some Operation inside ComponentDidMount method. I want to clear the Interval after I get props.status is completed.

```
class A extends React.PureComponent {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.intervalTimer = '';
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.intervalTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    // do something;
}, 3000);
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(np, ps) {
 if(np.status === 'completed') {
  clearInterval(A.intervalTimer);
}
}
}
```

Comment: what is `A.intervalTimer` after `clearInterval()`?

Comment: A is the class Name, since the getDerivedStateFromProps is static, we can access the class variable with Class Name isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create static variable and use that in `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle method.

Here `intervalTimer` is the variable which is accessible inside static method.

Here is the working code:-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

let intervalTimer = "";
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    stop: false
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    intervalTimer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("interval going on");
    }, 3000);
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ stop: true });
  };
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (state.stop) {
      clearInterval(intervalTimer);
    }
    return null;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Stop interval</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Or you could also use static variable instead of global variable

```
  static intervalTimer = ''

  componentDidMount() {
    App.intervalTimer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("interval going on");
    }, 3000);
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (state.stop) {
      clearInterval(App.intervalTimer);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Both approaches will work just fine.

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't allow getDerivedStateFromProps to change a none static variable or call a none static method. Its best to just return the new state from there. My suggestion will be for you to use a different life cycle method like

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // compare status props and clear timer
  if (this.props.status === 'completed') {
   clearInterval(this.intervalTimer);
  }
}
```

to be on a safe side also do the clearing inside

```
componentWillUnmount(){
 clearInterval(this.intervalTimer)
}
```

Comment: i did it using componentDidUpdate, but i was curious how to use it with static getDerivedStateFromProps..

Comment: Ok I see you might just be going against the design of the method getDerivedStateFromProps. Well in that case I think @tarzen answer should do